# How can I get the OpenVPN config file?

Tags: openvpn

I have a private VPS server at estnoc.ee. Through the computer I can get VPN, as I understand, by pptp.
I used to have openvpn working, but something must have updated or broken.  The person who did it for me is gone.
Is there any easy way to get a new openvpn config file?
Provider wrote me: "We do not provide itself openvpn configurations, we provide only vpses and dedicated servers with clean operating system. What programs client install into it, this is clients case mostly." and gave me the link https://phoenixnap.com/kb/openvpn-centos.
But it's insanely complicated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The only thing VPN-related thing I can find in Estnoc pages is Chinese sentence 沒有公共VPN & 沒有遊戲服務器 which Google translates to **No public VPN & no game servers** meaning you're not allowed to run a public VPN service or game server on a VPS hosted in Estnoc. That means you must be running your own private VPN in your VPS. If that's the case you need to dig into the documentation to find out how the server can provide config for clients.